# Lambda slots for QPushButtons in a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I have many `QPushButton`s in a `QTableWidget`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 1)
        l = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(table)
        self.setLayout(l)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('button '+str(i))
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnSlot(i))
            layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setLayout(layout)
            layout.addWidget(btn)
            table.setCellWidget(i, 0, container)

    def btnSlot(self, num):
        print(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Mainwindow()
    m.show()
    app.exec()
```

Why is this snippet printing `2` no matter which button I push?

I would expect `button 0` to print `0`, `button 1` to print `1` etc, since I connect to a lambda function with the loop counter `i`.

What do I have to change to get the behaviour I expect?

Comment: bcoz in the end, val of `i` is 2.

Comment: change `btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnSlot(i))` to `btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.btnSlot(i))`

Comment: @S.Nick Yup, that works. make it an answer.

Comment: @S.Nick whats the `ch` variable for?

Comment: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the i passed as a parameter to btnSlot is evaluated at the time btnSlot is called, NOT at the time the lambda is define. You need to freeze the value of i using a partial function, so:

```
from functools import partial

btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.btnSlot,i))
```

Another approach is to take advantage of the fact that default parameters are evaluated at the time function is defined, NOT at call time. So:

```
btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked,num=i: self.btnSlot(num))
```

Comment: Why are you using `partial` ***and*** `lambda`?

Comment: ekhumoro - you are right of course, the lambda is entirely superfluous. I suppose I just took the line from the question and amended it instead of rewriting it. Have now changed the answer.